# $\textbf{Reference Request:}$ Analytically Characterizing Basins of Attraction Boundaries and Measures

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, reference-request, dynamical-systems, basins-of-attraction

I understand that doing the above is not possible *in general*. However, when it *is* possible, what are common methods people use to analytically characterize basin of attraction boundaries (i.e. via a closed-form expression) or their (Lebesgue) measures?
Regarding the latter: I do not *necessarily* need an exact expression for their Lebesgue measure; anything that lets me say something *analytically* about the "size" of a basin of attraction would be great!) Any references or guidance would be immensely appreciated.

**More Details:** I have a nonlinear, first-order, autonomous system of $n\in\{2,3,...\}$ ODE defined on $[a,b]^n$, where $-\infty<a<b<\infty$.$^1$ I currently cannot solve for the exact solution, but I have identified the set of locally asymptotically stable (LAS) steady states $\{\vec{s}_1,...,\vec{s}_k\}$, where $k<\infty$. Each LAS steady state's basin of attraction seems to be very "well-behaved."$^2$.

---

**Footnotes:**
$\quad$ 1. That is, this system is only defined at points in $[a,b]^n$, and any trajectory originating in $[a,b]^n$ (and obeying this system) always remains in $[a,b]^n$.

$\quad$ 2. They are all simply connected. $k-1$ basins are convex sets; the remaining basin -- while non-convex -- just consists of the remaining space. The boundaries are "simple looking" and "smooth" (both in the colloquial sense). Note that these boundaries are not "flat" in the sense that they cannot be expressed as a hyperplane (or a finite union thereof).

Comment: This might be better asked on the mathoverflow site, where mathematicians gather.

Comment: Thanks @SuzuHirose! I had always asked my questions here... I didn't realize that there was *another* math Q&A site on here! (What's the difference?  is mathoverflow somehow... mathier? )

Comment: Those are actual mathematicians asking questions about research mathematics, this site is general mathematical things. I'm not saying you can't ask here or suggesting you shouldn't, just saying that your question seems to be about research, so it looks like it might get more answers there. Anyway I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: I see! You were still very helpful! It *is* about research, and I really appreciate you telling me about mathoverflow! That sounds perfect. Thanks so much agin!